# Facebook Like buttons behaving inconsistently

Tags: javascript, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have some like buttons that are behaving inconsistently. They work about one in every twenty clicks.

What I've noticed is that when they work, the node_type that's POSTed to Facebook is "link."

On the occasions that it doesn't work, the node_type is "page."

How is this node_type determined and why am I getting such inconsistent results?

Any help would be really appreciated.